# cypress mocha-junit-reporter generates empty junit xml file when there are test failures

Tags: junit, cypress

Can someone help me figure out why I'm not seeing test results in the junit output xml file.

My cypress.json file is configured like this:

```
  "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
     "testsuitesTitle": true,
     "mochaFile": "./cypress/reports/junit.xml"
  }
```

I run these like so:

```
start-server-and-test start-dev-env http://localhost:4200 cy:run
```

where start-dev-env is defined thus:

```
"start-dev-env": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy/dev${ENV_SPECIFIER}.json --live-reload=false",
```

If I have test failures, I get junit output like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="Mocha Tests" time="0.0000" tests="0" failures="0">
</testsuites>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that unless one adds a hash into the file name then later test suites overwrite earlier test suites resulting in loss of information.

So, the cypress.json should look like

```
  "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
 "reporterOptions": {
    "testsuitesTitle": true,
    "mochaFile": "./cypress/reports/junit.[hash].xml"
 }
```

The hash gets replaced with a date-time hash and then you'll have a bunch of test xml files to process.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer above, if you would like to merge all these multiple `junit.[hash].xml` created into a single `mergedreport.xml` report, then you can use this package [junit-report-merger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-report-merger) which is useful for running it on CI pipeline which usually looks for a single reporter with a command like the one below:

`jrm ./cypress/reports/mergedreport.xml "./cypress/reports/junit*.xml"`